# iOS 8 UITabBar selectionIndicatorImage leaves rounded rectangle

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am creating a sample "Tabbed Application project" with Xcode 6.3. The tab bar is configured in the Storyboard view, and its configuration is set thus:

[image]

As you can see, the `Selection` part is set to an empty string, which is the default value.

However, when running the app in the simulator, the tab bar looks like this:

[image]

There is this weird semi-transparent blue rectangular background around the selected item. So what I tried is setting the selection item to the string literal "foobar," which does not exist in my project. This yields the result I was looking for:

[image]
[image]

The weird blue background is gone. And yet, I don't think this is the preferred way of doing this, and it might (definitely will) confuse future developers. So how *should* it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button shapes is most likely on in Settings, under General>Accessibility.

Changing it to foobar fixes it because it sets the selected one to a tab that doesn't exist, therefore making button shape think that it is that instead of the original view controller.